# Chrome extension for adding annotations/markups on the page

Tags: chrome

I am looking for Chrome extension which will allow me to make some annotation on any website, like adding the objects on top of the page such as lines, arrows, text, using some kind of pen or brush tool to mark some areas or any similar visual annotation depending on the availability.

So after making annotation, I expect that changes should be remembered and visible after reload of that page.

Here is the example bar from *Preview* what I mean:

[image: Preview app, Markup Toolbar]

Answer (score 1):

**[Diigo Web Collector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/diigo-web-collector-captu/pnhplgjpclknigjpccbcnmicgcieojbh?hl=en)** allows you to highlight and comment parts of a web page (or PDF), which will be kept after reloading. Those parts are also accessible from their web page and are meant to help you perform research. You cannot put arrows and lines on the web page, but it allows you to take a screenshot of the relevant part and apply those parts to it.

Changing a screenshot should also be preferable to trying to place something on a web page because those drawings and arrows can never adjust properly their position and scale (and would point to something else when you open the page again), because the entire layout on most web pages depends on the window size.

Answer (score 0):

[Evernote's web clipper](https://evernote.com/products/webclipper/) handles the annotation part but I don't think they stay visible after reloading the page though.